Excel - Power Query - Calculated Column (Minimum Value)
I'm trying to create a column that only contains the minimum value of another column but keep running into an error.  See below:
Power Query Window :

Any idea as to what is going on.  It seems like the formula should work.  Do I have some kind of formatting issue going on?
Thank you

In a calculated column, you're only getting that row's value, not the whole column (because the UI changes that into an each function). You'll need to refer to the previous step - e.g. List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Days Until Due])

So the each part needs to be removed?  What would the Table.AddColumn function need to look like?  I've tried a few different variations and keep getting errors.  This was my latest:  = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Minimum", List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Days Until Due]))

Put the each back into that version: Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Minimum", each List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Days Until Due])) Although you'd probably be better off calculating that as a separate step and then just referring to it.

That did it.  Thank  you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
